# How do i store this data correctly? Application freezes

Tags: c#, mysql, freeze

I'm trying to save MySQL data in a sort of session for my program.

The code I have is this:

```
 sessionData userSession = new sessionData();
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; )
 {
     userSession.UserData[i] = reader.GetString(i).ToString();
 }
```

sessionData.cs

```
class sessionData
{
    public string[] UserData = new string[7];
}
```

I'm then trying to access the users first name and display it like so:

```
welcomeBox.Text = "Hi, " + userData.UserData[1] + ".";
```

However, once I press Login it freezes before my application goes to the landing page.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is an infinite loop, until you add the i ++ in it

`for (int i = 0; i < 7; )` should change to 
`for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++;)`

Also code review notes:

- Why are your class names beginning with lower case letters? Majority of .NET projects use CamelCase.
- Your question has been edited for grammer and syntax. Next time put more effort in your questions, and before falling back to stack overflow, try out things for yourself first.

Comment: Look for the green tick mark left of this answer to flag it as correct.